# Visual Studio App Center Android Build for react native failed with error "Unable to resolve module os.."

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to automate the android build for my app which is built in the react native platform. But I am getting the following error everytime

Unable to resolve module `os` from `/Users/vsts/agent/2.136.1/work/1/s/node_modules/airbrake-js/dist/client.js`: Module does not exist in the module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.

:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

  > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I can't figure out how to resolve this issue. Any suggestion will be appreciated.